# How to access a variable inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am extremely new to javascript so apologize for questions that may be trivial ?

```
var foo = function () {
    a = "10";
    this.b = "20"; 
};

foo.c = "30";

console.log(foo.a); // undefined
console.log(foo.c); // prints 30.

var foo1 = new foo();
console.log(foo1.b) // prints 20
```

How to access var "a" ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: You could always use global variables.

Comment: @JCOC611 How to access var "a" ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: it is not.  This is a form of a private scope variable.

Comment: wrong. a is in the global scope (not prefixed with var)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, as long as you don't prefix the variable declaration with `var` it will be global:

```
var foo = function () {
    a = "10";
    this.b = "20"; 
};

foo();

console.log(a); // is 10
```

Compared to:

```
var foo = function () {
    var a = "10"; // private scope
    this.b = "20"; 
};

foo();  

console.log(a); // is undefined
```

Comment: @6502: I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Using global variables:

```
var a = 10;
var foo = function() {
    a = 15;
    this.b = 20;
};
console.log(a); // equals 10
foo();
console.log(a); // equals 15
```

If you wanted to actually access the variable `a` within the function, much like your example:

```
var foo = function() {
    a = 10; // private member
};
```

<strike>There is no way to access that private member.</strike>

Turns out when you declare a variable in this way, you have created a global variable. You can access it with `console.log(a);` and it will return `10`. However if you use `var a = 10;` inside the function, you will not be able to access this member.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
console.log(foo.a);
console.log(foo.c);
```

implies that you believe that `a` would be set as the equivalent of `foo.a = "10"`, that is setting a static field of the "class" `foo`. This is not the case in JavaScript.

```
 a = "10";
```

This sets the global variable `a` to the value `"10"`, creating a global variable slot if necessary. This type of global assignment should be avoided and is caught by tools like JSLint.

```
 this.b = "20";
```

This sets the field of the object passed as the `this` parameter of the function to `"20"`, creating the field slot if necessary. Note that if you call `foo` directly, e.g. `foo()`, without `new`, the global scope is passed as `this` and `this.b` will also create a global variable. This type of error can be caught by strict mode. If you execute in strict mode, `undefined` is passed in as the `this` parameter and this will throw an exception.

```
var foo1 = new foo();
```

This creates a new, empty, object with the `__proto__` property set to the value of the `prototype` property of `foo` and then calls `foo` passing the new object as the `this` parameter. All fields of `__proto__` appear as the default values of fields of the object. This leads to the convention of adding methods to the `prototype` object of the constructor function and initializing fields in the constructor function. Inheritance can be simulated by constructing an object with the ancestor prototype object as its `__proto__` value and assigning it to the functions `prototype` property of the constructor function. The constructor function would also call the ancestor constructor function (without `new`), passing its `this` as the constructor function's `this` parameter (using `apply` or `call`). This is all a bit awkward so ECMAScript 6 standardized this into a `class` construct which roughly translates to what I described.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is return an object in your constructor that defines public members:

```
function Foo() {
    var a = '10';

    function getA() {
        return a;
    }

    return {
        'a': a,
        'b': 20,
        'getA': getA
    };
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.a) // 10
console.log(foo.b); // 20
console.log(foo.getA()); // 10
```